# Selecting individual elements in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've used the following code to create several rectangles and place them in a horizontal line:

```
 var nodeIcons = svg.selectAll(".node")
     .data(line.nodes)
     .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("x", screenWidth+100);

     lastX = 50;
     nodeIcons.transition().attr("x", function(d){
         lastX += 150;
         return lastX;
         }).duration(1000);
```

As you can see, the rectangles are initially placed at the same x coordinate off the left edge of the screen, then they are animated into their place on the line.

Now, what would I call if I wanted to move just the first node in the line a bit further to the left?

I'm trying to wrap my head around the fundamentals of d3, here, and what I'm primarily asking is how to ***select*** the first node on the line.

Comment: `d3.select(d3.selectAll(".node")[0][0])`

Comment: @StephenThomas What do indexes `[0]` and `[0]` refer to?

Comment: The first `[0]` is there to handle d3 groupings, but since you're not doing that, it will always be 0. The second `[0]` is the specific node you're interested in. The first node is numbered 0, the second is numbered 1, etc.

Comment: @StephenThomas Also, is my initial instinct correct that, since `nodeIcons` has already been defined as `svg.selectAll(".node")`, calling `d3.select(nodeIcons[0][0])` would be equivalent to calling `d3.select(d3.selectAll(".node")[0][0])`?

Comment: you haven't defined `nodeIcons` that way; you've set it to the `rect` elements that you've appended.

Comment: @StephenThomas Interesting. That helps. Thanks. So now, if I wanted to   get ahold of the data bound to the rectangle I've selected, i.e. the corresponding object in the data array, what would I call?

Comment: note that d3 handles `append` differently than jQuery. In jQuery, `$("<div>").append($sel)` returns the parent `<div>`, while in d3, `d3.select('div').append('span')` returns the appended `<span>`

Comment: and to answer your question, you didn't bind the data to the rect, you bound it to the elements with class 'node'.

Comment: @StephenThomas So how *should* I have initialized the rects, assuming that I want to bind them each to an object in the data array?

Comment: Seems like this has probably gotten a little out of hand for a comment thread. Might I point you to an old blog post of mine: http://blog.sathomas.me/post/web-based-visualization-part-1-the-d3.js-key-concept If that doesn't work for you Dr. Google definitely knows about lots of other d3 resources (probably too many ;^)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you probably want to give the class that you've selected the elements by to the created elements:

```
var nodeIcons = svg.selectAll(".node")
 .data(line.nodes)
 .enter().append("rect")
 .attr("class", "node")
 .attr("x", screenWidth+100);
```

To select just the first of these, you could either use `.selectAll()` and then index into the selection as pointed out in the comments, or simply use `svg.select(".node")`, which will give you the first element that matches.

D3 uses CSS selectors and these are quite flexible when it comes to things like this. If you wanted to select the 4th element for example, you could do something like this:

```
svg.select("rect:nth-child(4)");
```

In general, a better way to do this is to assign IDs to the elements so that you can select them explicitly though:

```
svg.append("rect").attr("id", "foo");

svg.select("#foo");
```